# how to remove some empty space from inside of html

Tags: php, html

I don't know how to describe my question because I don't even know this is an error or not!

In most of my works there are some empty space inside html.

I know some space or other special characters are skip from rendering of browsers but this one never skips!

[image]

in my php file I have one include exactly near that space.

how can I remove that? thanks in advance...

```
<div class="pg-picture">
    <img src="img/top-pic/1375022681.jpg" alt="" width="353px" height="145px" /></div>            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <script type="text/javascript">
    setTitle('title');
</script>
```

css:

```
html,body,.container{min-height:100%}
.container{margin:0 auto;position:relative;width:990px}

html>body .clearfix:after{clear:both;content:" ";display:block;font-size:0;height:0;visibility:hidden;*zoom:1}
* html .clearfix{height:1%}
```

Comment: Step 1: Show us your actual source code - not output from the "Inspector" tab, as it fixes HTML and other things. (*Hint; right click -> view source*)

Comment: Look if there is any `echo "\n"` in your php code

Comment: also need your css for container and clearfix - clearfix usually use pseudo elements that adds empty content

Comment: you have broken html in your sample

Comment: It must be `.clearfix` causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `content:" "` in your css to `content=""`.

[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: I did that before but nothing changed.